# Why do i receive an error message in the console that getStoredQuests.push is not a function at Object.addQuestionOnLocalStorage

Tags: javascript

Why do I receive an error message in the console that `getStoredQuests.push` is not a function at `Object.addQuestionOnLocalStorage`

```
class Question{
    constructor(id, questionText, options, correctAnswer) {
        this.id = id;
        this.questionText = questionText;
        this.options = options;
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    }
}

let questionLocalStorage = {
    setQuestionCollection: (newQuestion) => {
        localStorage.setItem('questionCollection', JSON.stringify(newQuestion));
    },
    getQuestionCollection: () => {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('questionCollection'));
    },
    removeQuestionCollection: () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('questionCollection');
    }
}
```

```
newQuestion = new Question(questionId, newQuestText.value, optionsArr, corrAnswer);

getStoredQuests = questionLocalStorage.getQuestionCollection();

getStoredQuests.push(newQuestion);

questionLocalStorage.setQuestionCollection(getStoredQuests);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because `getStoredQuests` is not an array. You have probably not considered if there is no question in local storage initially, then `localStorage.getItem('questionCollection')` will return empty string or it might be case that you have some value with key `questionCollection` in local storage but is not in proper format to to be parsed as JSON array object.

For the first case solution is to check if `localStorage.getItem('questionCollection')` is empty then return empty array from `getQuestionCollection` and for the second case you to need to properly format the array '(serialize the array to be stored with JSON.stringify)'.

*To let your problem understand properly, open up console see if there are red lines*

Comment: I have used: if (questionLocalStorage.getQuestionCollection() === null) {
  questionLocalStorage.setQuestionCollection([]);
 }